# Can we use "off-chance" in a scientific paper?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, word-usage

In an article that I'm writing, I would like to say that some special ideas are at a disadvantage concerning their consistency in producing results. In other words, we use those approaches in the hope of getting a reasonable result, but the methods are presently poorly understood, so we can only hope for a good result. So please help me to correct any grammatical deficiencies in the quoted sentence:

> The main disadvantage to these approaches is that they tend to be on the off chance.

"These" refers to the mentioned approaches in a previous sentence. Is *off chance* correct here? Is it OK to use in a scientific paper?

Comment: I added the questions I think you are asking in order to make it clearer what you want answered. Please feel free to edit it if I have misinterpreted your intent.

Comment: And just to make sure the point isn't lost in the fascinating detail: "off-chance" doesn't imply just uncertainty (that would be "chancey" or "unpredictable"), it implies **low** probability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The construction

> X on the off chance Y

Indicates that some action (described by a complete clause X) is undertaken in hopes that it brings about (but probably will not) another action (described by complement clause Y).

Y (which is **required**) must be a complement clause introduced by *that* (*that* could be omitted in informal styles, but keep it in for a research paper). A model usage would be:

> David took the 7:30 train home on the off chance that he would see Mira.

Furthermore, Y usually has a modal auxiliary as its finite verb (*could*, *would*, *might*, *should*).

To reword your sample sentence so that it fits the template for this expression,

> The main disadvantage of these approaches is that they tend to be undertaken *on the off chance* that they could succeed, rather than with definite expectations about when they will bear fruit.

A commenter has correctly pointed out that Y could also be a gerundive verb phrase introduced by the preposition *of* (e.g., "of succeeding", "of finding a way out of the cave"), as in

> David took the 7:30 train home on the off chance of seeing Mira.

A slight variant of the construction is a type of conditional construction:

> (If) On the off chance Y, X.

Which indicates some action represented by X that should be taken in the (unlikely) event that Y occurs. Here, Y usually does not have as its finite verb a modal auxiliary. e.g.,

> (If) On the off chance that you see butter at the store, buy two pounds.

Comment: +1 By the way, it's great that you don't use unnecessary abbreviations. Makes your answers so much more readable than some linguistic treatises that would otherwise be perfectly clear.

Comment: +1 You might add that a Y is **required**, which is what OP's attempt misses. In your first examples, where the phrase means something like "with the unlikely hope", Y may also be a prepositional phrase headed by *of*: "on the off chance of seeing Mira", "on the off chance of success/succeding". I'd regard the second use, "in the unlikely event", as a mis-use, but I'm an old fart and history is trending away from me.

Comment: Correction: required, or elliptically implied. "You're unlikely to succeed." "Yes, well, I'm doing it on the off chance."

Answer (score 2):

Correct?  I'm not sure, but to my own ear, for some reason your example does not sound quite right.  Per the OED, an *off-chance* is:

> **b.** ***off chance, off-chance,*** a contingency out of the probable course; a remote chance, a by-chance.

One of their citations illustrates how the term is normally used:

> - 1893 Stevenson *Beach of Falesá* 144, ― I thought there was an off-chance he might go back on the whole idea.

Also, I prefer the hyphenated version myself.

Comment: But according to Longman Dictionary, When I looked up "chance" I found this: On the off chance: if you do something on the off chance, you do it hoping for a particular result, although you know it is not likely.

Comment: How do you feel about using *off-chance* as in your quotation, that is, outside the construction *on the off-chance that*? Is it still used in modern prose?

Comment: @Cerberus I *think* it might be ok as written, even today.

Comment: I prefer the hyphenated version too, and I agree it doesn't sound quite right in OP's construction. Also, since no-one else seems to have mentioned it, I'll just say that to my ear, doing anything *on the off-chance [of something turning out to be the case]* sounds decidedly informal. So I wouldn't even *consider* using it in a scientific paper.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the idiom isn’t quite right and, so, is inappropriate for (scientific) publication.  How about:

> The main disadvantage of these approaches is that they {fail to}/{do not} consistently deliver/yield reliable/accurate/usable results

(Yes, one of these options contains a split infinitive, up to you—or the journal—to choose whether you follow that anti-split fashion.)

The *off chance* idiom could be used in a talk:

> We employed these approaches on the off chance that they work(ed), though in several cases they didn’t.

For me at least, though, I can only *do something on the off chance*.  Something cannot *be on the off chance*.

Answer (score 0):

I think *off-chance* could be used in a scientific paper, but not in this context.

> *"The main disadvantage .. is that they tend to be on the off chance"*

sounds decidedly informal and in need of a rewrite.  (In general, I often find myself rewriting sentences that have the construct, "The main X is that...")  In other words, I would change:

> The main problem I have with this sentence is that I don't think it's well-constructed.

to something more direct, such as:

> I have a problem with this sentence: it is not well-constructed.

or, more simply:

> This sentence is not well-constructed.

So, your sentence could be reworded:

> These results tend to be on the off-chance, which is a disadvantage.

and I think that would be an improvement.

But, getting to the heart of your question, I still don't like it, because of the phrase *on the off chance.*  NOAD lists ***on the off chance*** as an idiom meaning, "just in case," and offers this example usage: *Joan phoned at noon on the off chance that he’d be home.*  I don't think it's good to describe *results* as "just in case."  I think what you really want to say is:

> These results are produced inconsistently, which is a disadvantage.